# How to pass Build Number variable from Jenkinsfile to bat file

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have created Jenkins file which has current build number. I want to pass this Build Number Variable to .bat file. How Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables like `JOB_NAME` and `BUILD_NUMBER` are set automatically by Jenkins, just use them in batch files as `%JOB_NAME%` and `%BUILD_NUMBER%`.

See more in [the Jenkinsfile documentation about environment variables](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables).